# how to efficiently insert bulk data set into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, command, symfony5

I have some question regarding the symfony5 command class and how to efficiently insert ca. 10 million entries (only one entity with an Uuid field and without any relation to other entities). The whole gimmick has no purposes, and is only needed in order to run some test with elasticsearch.

Right now, while inserting the data, everything works so far ok, but it last for hours (20k / h).

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfVochers; $i++) {

        $voucher = new Voucher();
        $voucher->setCode(Uuid::v4());
        $voucher->setValid(new DateTime());
      
        $this->em->persist($voucher);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
```

What I am supposed to do (except to get rid of my hardware: Macbook Pro 2,3 GHz Intel Core i5, 8GB) to get this job faster?

Comment: It really depends on how the table is structured and the size of the dataset. Have you tried to disable the indexes?

Comment: Given the lack of code, we can't tell you if it's your code or not. However what @EnricoDias touched on is a factor, if you're inserting every record in its own transaction that will cause several tiny write operations for each statement. Disabling indexes temporarily is one workaround, another would be to explicitly open a transaction in which to do these inserts. The idea is to have mysql roll up all the tiny write operations into larger, more efficient batches.

Comment: @EnricoDias, the table consist only of 2 fields, uuid and datetime. There are no indexes set.

Comment: @Sammitch, its an simple for loop with 10 Million iteration that's all. and inside the loop:     
            $voucher = new Voucher();
            $voucher->setCode(Uuid::v4());
            $voucher->setValid(new DateTime());
            $this->em->persist($voucher);
            $this->em->flush();

Comment: Have you tried to encapsulate the whole operation in the same transaction as @Sammitch said? You also need to take into account your storage device capability. You'll be always limited by the maximum write speed of your hd/ssd.

Comment: A multi-row INSERT is much faster than a bunch of 1-row inserts.  Up to 10 times as fast.  (I don't know how to express that in the 3rd-party-package-du-jour.

Comment: thank you all, especially @Sammitch for the hint with the transactions. It works right now as expected and therefore I would like to upvote your answer but unfortunately your answer is an comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing you should probably perform bulk updates, e.g. like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfVochers; $i++) {
    $voucher = new Voucher();
    $voucher->setCode(Uuid::v4());
    $voucher->setValid(new DateTime());
      
    $this->em->persist($voucher);
    if ($i % 100) {
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
$this->em->flush(); // just in case the last badge was not added
```

Additionally you should call `$this->em->clear()` after each flush, to ensure you don't run into memory issues. In your case `$voucher` does not rely on previously inserted data, so `clear()` should not pose any issues.

Since this action is performed in bulk you can now update your command to partition the creation, i.e. instead of calling your command once for all vouchers you could start the process 4 times for 1/4 of the vouchers. Then you have 4 processes doing the insert, which usually speeds up performance as each process can run on a different processor. In your case, since each voucher can be created independently this should not be much work. In other cases you probably have to tailor your command to be able to partition the work properly.

Alternatively you can also use threading in your command (can't recommend) or use something like the messenger to split up the task into batches, send a message for each batch and then use a number of workers to process the messages.

Comment: that sounds resonable to me, i will give it a try. thank you.